# how to display selected text and value using knokoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

here is my select mark-up

```
 <select multiple=true data-placeholder="Filter from Coederfirst.com" data-bind=" options: skillTags, selectedOptions: selectedSkillTags,  optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'LookUpId' ,chosen: {width: '100%'}"></select>
```

here is my view model

```
var viewModel = {

skillTags: ko.observableArray(),
selectedSkillTags: ko.observableArray(),
```

};

here is the code to display selected text

```
     <ul class="tags" data-bind="foreach:selectedSkillTags">
                                        <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
                                    </ul>
```

but it display only selected value only. so how to display select text and value

Comment: Remove optionsValue: 'LookUpId' and it will instead use the object reference as selected value instead of the LookUpId

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove, `optionsValue: 'LookUpId'`

http://jsfiddle.net/fwc29/